# Accept parameters in the combination of columns for retrieving many records

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Table1 has 4 columns = **Col1 , Col2 , Col3 , Col4**

Col1 is id(integer) column = **156 , 159 , 175**

Col2 is varchar column = **CAA , DFE , EME**

Col3 is varchar column = **12345 , 23465 , 43122**

Col4 is varchar column = **2 , 3 , 6**

I am creating a stored procedure which accepts collection of combinations as parameters

**Combinations** = Col2 + Col3 + Col4 which returns Col1 value. Similarly to accept collections and returns many values (Col1)

**For Example** : Need to get the inputs CAA + 12345 + 2 has to return 156. Similarly DFE + 23465 + 43122 has to return 159.

How to accept parameters in the stored procedure for the above scenario? How to accept parameters in the combination of columns for retrieving many records in SQL Server?

Comment: @DaleK, As I don't know the approach, I have asked the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have explored and found the solution.

I have created a `table type` - having 3 fields

Then, I have used this table type in the `stored procedure` accepting as a parameter

Then, I have used inner join to accomplish my task.

Answer (score 0):

```
create proc spstack
@col2 varchar(10),
@col3 varchar(10),
@col4 varchar(10)
as begin
select col1 from #stack where
col2=@col2 and col3=@col3 and col4=@col4
end
execute spstack 'CAA','12345','2'
output-156
```

Comment: How to implement for capturing more than 1 inputs

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [procedure-name]
@Col2 nvarchar(3),
@Col3 nvarchar(5),
@Col4 nvarchar(1)

SELECT Col1 from Table1
WHERE Col2 = @Col2 AND Col3 = @Col3 AND Col4 = @Col4
```

Hope this is what you're asking and helps!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).